# Flink Savepoint Timeout

Tags: apache-flink

I use Flink version 1.11 and have timout issue during savepoint

[image: timeout exception snapshot]

My savepoint size is around 4Gb ++
How to increase the savepoint timeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, refer to the [Enabling and Configuring Checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/checkpointing.html#enabling-and-configuring-checkpointing) section of flink documentation.

You can increase the savepoint timeout to 1 minute via

```java
// checkpoints have to complete within one minute, or are discarded
env.getCheckpointConfig().setCheckpointTimeout(60000);
```

I would also recommend to increase the minimum time between checkpoints to make sure that the streaming application makes a certain amount of progress between checkpoints via

```java
// make sure 500 ms of progress happen between checkpoints
env.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(500);
```

Comment: Thanks @mikalai-lushchytski for your quick answer. Is it the same between checkpoint and savepoint setting?

Comment: hi @HanChris! Yes, it's the same as internally checkpoints and savepoints are basically using the same code and produce the same format.

Comment: is there any work around to change that in config level? (flink-conf.yaml) instead of changing the source code? @mikalai-lushchytski

Comment: To be honest, I only configured this inside the code, but the document reference https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/config.html#checkpointing also shows `flink-conf.yaml`-level options available - for example, `execution.checkpointing.timeout`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, as you can see from my very similar logs:

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Triggering a savepoint for the job 63a70a46cf5bffda3ca0a1e791113122 failed.
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.triggerSavepoint(CliFrontend.java:777)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$savepoint$9(CliFrontend.java:754)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runClusterAction(CliFrontend.java:1002)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.savepoint(CliFrontend.java:751)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1072)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1784)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.triggerSavepoint(CliFrontend.java:771)
... 10 more
```

The cause was not that the savepoint was timing out, but rather that the client communication was timing out.

For me, this was happening on EMR.  Editing `/etc/flink/conf.dist/flink-conf.yaml` on the master node to add the following, which increased the timeout to 5 minutes, did the trick:

> akka.client.timeout: 300000

For some additional color, the savepoint size I was working with was 160.3 GiB pulled from 4 instances.